# Extend Linux Desktop to another X Windows Display

Tags: linux, laptop, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, x-windows

I am a long time Linux user of the Xinerama and other technologies for extending a desktop to multiple monitors. However when I travel with my laptop I miss the multi-monitor support I enjoy at home. Recently I acquired a second laptop for a low price. Both laptops are running Fedora (versions 10 and 11 respectively). I use Gnome as my primary desktop environment.

I know about synergy. I use synergy all the time to control the screen of other Windows / Linux systems I use.

I would like to know, can I sit both my primary and secondary laptops together and achieve a Xinerama-like extended desktop environment? Ideally I would like to start a GNOME session on my primary laptop. And then start a X-Windows Desktop on my secondary laptop and extend my primary laptop's desktop onto it. I would like to be able to move Windows from the primary desktop to the secondary laptop desktop.

Would I need to use synergy to do this with some other bit of X-Windows technology? Or is there X-Windows technology that will do all this for me?

I am familiar with X Windows ability to display applications remotely. I am also familiar with Nomachine's NoX.

Answer (score 8):

I think you are looking for http://dmx.sourceforge.net/ .  From the man page:

It provides multi-head X functionality for displays that might be located on different machines.

Comment: Great! Great! Great!

Comment: -1 The other is greater! Greater! Greater!

Answer (score 6):

Start the X server with the -ac option, in all Linux box that you want to make the `wall`, like:

```
X -ac
```

Then execute startx, with Xdmx with xinerama enabled, sending the `display` to the server, as:

```
startx -- /usr/bin/Xdmx :0 +xinerama -display 10.0.0.1:0.0 -display 10.0.0.2:0.0 -display 10.0.0.3:0.0 -norender -noglxproxy
```

Comment: Be careful about using `X -ac`, as it [disables access control mechanisms](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/Xserver.1.html). Consider setting up ssh X11 forwarding instead.

Answer (score 1):

## Virtual Monitor Over VNC

With this solution you can use any OS that is able to connect via VNC to your Ubuntu machine like a second screen. This is done by using [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/), the following is derived from the [VNC Virtual Display Linker](https://github.com/mrenrich84/vnc_virtual_display_linker) python code. I had a couple of issues with this code but I managed to get it working as shown below.

### Simplified Intructions:

Please be aware of the notes and considerations at the end of this answer.

1. **Definitions:** The "server" will be the computer which screen you want to extend, the "client" will be the computer (or tablet, any device able to deploy a VNC client) that you want to use as a screen.
2. **Required Software**: On the server install `x11vnc` and `gtf`, on the client install a vnc client.
3. You need to know client's screen size (we'll call them: `CLIENT_WIDTH`, `CLIENT_HEIGHT`) and the servers' screen size (we'll call them: `SERVER_WIDTH`, `SERVER_HEIGHT`).
4. In the server, run in a terminal `gtf CLIENT_WIDTH CLIENT_HEIGHT 60` (replace the `CLIENT_WIDTH` and `CLIENT_HEIGHT` with the corresponding values). As an example for `gtf CLIENT_WIDTH CLIENT_HEIGHT 60` is

```
# 1384x768 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 47.70 kHz; pclk: 86.62 MHz
Modeline "1384x768_60.00"  86.62  1384 1456 1600 1816  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync
```

5. From the previous result copy what is in front of `Modeline`, (in this case `"1384x768_60.00"  86.62  1384 1456 1600 1816  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync`) and use that as a parameter to `xrandr --newmode` command. For example, in this case, we'll have to run in the server `xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"  85.86  1368 1440 1584 1800  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync`
6. In 5 we've created a newmode in `xrandr`, now we need to add it to the virtual screen, as follows `xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 "1368x768_60.00"` (please remember to use your own newly created mode name, which is the value including quotes in 5).
7. Run `x11vnc -usepw -nocursorshape -nocursorpos -noxinerama -solid -repeat -forever -clip CLIENT_WIDTHxCLIENT_HEIGHT+SERVER_WIDTH+0`. As an example: `x11vnc -usepw -nocursorshape -nocursorpos -noxinerama -solid -repeat -forever -clip 1368x768+1920+0`. This will create a VNC server in port `5900` you can connect to.
8. Lastly, connect to the server from you other computer (or any VNC client, recommended `krdc` for linux machines). You should be able to enjoy your extended screen now.

### Notes and considerations:

- In step 8, with krdc, it is recommended to use the "Medium Quality" option, even if you are on cable: both the "Low" and "High" quality options produce errors.
- I tried this over a WiFi network and it works properly, however on cable it's smoother.
- I had problems when starting the VNC server in step 7, the screen started to flicker and I couldn't see what I was doing on the screen. To fix this, I connected via the VNC server (the extended screen already works at this point), opened the `Displays` tool (the one that comes with the system where you can see the displays that are connected) and `Unify Outputs` then `Break Unified Outputs`
  (an example of this option in Kubuntu is shown below). Then everything worked.

[image: Unify Outputs]