# Configure Linux to act as an additional desktop or extended display to client

Tags: linux, display, external-display, iot

Let's say I have 2 computers.

**Computer 1:** Runs Linux. Let's say Debian, or Ubuntu, Raspbian, etc if that matters. It controls a nice large display that I'd like to utilize.

**Computer 2:** We can assume it also runs the same kind of Linux if necessary, though relaxing that assumption to "any major OS like Windows, Apple's OS, or Linux" would be even better.

Thusfar I've been using SSH + an automation shell script I wrote to copy images created by Python/R on *Computer 2* to *Computer 1* for automatic fullscreen display. This is clunky because it's only jpeg plots created in 1 specific directory with a specific filename pattern.

I would like to improve it to something more like just extending the display. This may sound like a waste of resources on *Computer 1*, but this is just 1 function *Computer 1* will be doing for some of the time.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/395227/using-spare-pc-as-second-monitor

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/71794/extend-linux-desktop-to-another-x-windows-display

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/136942/extend-desktop-to-monitor-over-lan and https://askubuntu.com/questions/456062/use-windows-laptop-as-second-screen-to-ubuntu-laptop

Answer (score 2):

Yup: [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy).

It's been around a while and remains well-recommended. Though, full disclosure, I have not used it myself.

Synergy is a multi-platform (Windows, MacOS, Linux) application that allows you to, among other things, use the monitor connected to one computer as though it were a screen connected to a different computer and extend your desktop.

Comment: I thought Synergy allowed sharing the same mouse and keyboard across system, but not displays. (Can’t drag a window across PCs)

Comment: Thanks so much, that looks awesome! The comment above is making me a little paranoid. I am more than happy to mark this as the solution, but could you confirm if the comment above is accurate? I see the feature list here https://symless.com/synergy/features   I don't see it listed (?). I want to try it but it cost $29 so can you let me know? Cheers! Thanks so much. The $29 price is fine as long as it works, but it seems like that's not a feature...

Comment: When I first found Synergy it was clearly stated the primary purpose was this extended desktop, and how-to's online referencing it refer to using it for that purpose as well. However, as noted, I haven't actually used it myself, so I cannot confirm at this moment. There may be a way to contact them on Social Media to ask this. I'll see what I can learn. https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/use-laptop-like-external-monitor/

Comment: Eh, the more I look, the more it appears you are correct and while a large number of apparently second-rate recommendation articles report Synergy as the primary and preferred solution for what you describe, it does not, in fact, offer the feature you're requesting. Interestingly, Windows 10 contains this ability natively, with the ability to broadcast your screen as being connectable, and then the ability to connect to a wireless display.